# Using headset mic for recording screenshot video

Tags: windows-8, screen-capture, headset

I want to use my blackberry smartphone headset's mic for recording an onscreen video but all i can get is the earphones acting as a mic themselves. I don't want that, I want to use the headset mic and not it's earphones as mic.

In fact I recorded a video earlier, a month or so back. I plugged in the headset in either mic or headphones jack of the laptop(can't seem to remember but it worked)

Now, I am just not able to use the headset's mic. I used the debut capture software earlier and using the same now. What can be difference or wrong this time around??

Motto is to use the headset mic for recording. I have a toshiba c650 laptop running windows 8 with two separate jacks for mic and headphone.